# R from command line, view window with all variables with values

Tags: r

I use R and MATLAB from the command line and edit files with external editors. In MATLAB, the command `workspace` opens a graphical window with a list of all variables **and the current values**. If I double click on a complex object, like a matrix, MATLAB automatically opens another window with a table containing the values.

*Is there any similar way to do so in R?*

In [this link](https://www.personality-project.org/r/r.commands.html), in the end of the first "box", it is listed the command `browse.workspace`, which seems what I am looking for. Unfortunately I cannot invoke it.

I tried with commands which prints output in the terminal (like `str(as.list(.GlobalEnv))`) but I do not like the result. When I have got a lot of variables it is a big mess.

Comment: you can use `ls` to list all object in your workspace instead of `str(as.list(.GlobalEnv))`

Comment: `ls` does not show me the value of the variables

Comment: could `ls.str` suits your need ? you can filter by name and mode. `lsf.str` is the same for functions in your workspace. I do not know any graphical windows from command line. You need to use RStudio, Rcommander or other GUI for that I think

Comment: @cderv it is a bit better than the command above, thank you. Actually I am using emacs and not just a random editor plus the command line, so I will ask in the emacs forum if they know an emacs function to show all the variables and matrices (and this would be even better that a graphical interface), but I am afraid that there isn't.

Comment: RStudio editor has emacs keybinding compatibility. Don't know what it worth but if you want to give it a try... I gave you all I know. Good luck.